# Why am I not able to move some bones?

Tags: rigging, bones

I tried myself on doing a rig for a low poly crab and somehow I changed some settings without realising. Now I'm not able to move the bones except of the base. Normally, if I select one, it looks like this:

[image]

If i try to move it now this happens:

[image]

Comment: you are in edit mode for the rig, switch to pose mode.

Answer (score 2):

A bone is defined by two points, known as the head and tail of the bone. When you select one of these points you only move that point, the bone/s defined by that point then stretch to fit the opposite point.

[image: moving tip of bone]

If you want to move both points of a bone together you select both points. Clicking the body of the bone will select both points for you.

[image: moving both end of bone]

While I don't think it applies to you, you can [lock the points](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/rigging/armatures/bones/properties/introduction.html#transform) of a bone in the bone transform properties, so that they can't be moved in edit mode. If this is the case, it is a matter of turning off the lock.